Working with Arrays in Hasura Permissions
I have a postgres table with a bunch of people along with their state, county, city, etc. The way my application is set up, my users can have access to an entire state, or a county, or a city.
On hasura, I am trying to set up permissions for the people table as follows:
Let's take the county field for example:
{
"county":{"_in":"X-Hasura-Allowed-Counties"}
}

This works well for users who have access to one or more counties. But for users who have access to an entire state, I need a way to tell my permissions to allow all counties. I cannot skip this header because the permission structure expects the X-Hasura-Allowed-Counties header to be present.
I am unable to figure out a way to specify a value for X-Hasura-Allowed-Counties header which will allow all counties.
I already tried specifying my permission like:
{
  "_or": [
    {
      "county": {
        "_in": "X-Hasura-Allowed-Counties"
      }
    },
    {
      "X-Hasura-Allowed-Counties": {
        "_eq": "*"
      }
    }
  ]
}

But this does not work, since Hasura does not allow checking for the header value in the permissions JSON.
Thanks for any help!
